# Add marker to android google map with async task

Tags: android, json, google-maps

I have an async task which I am trying to add map markers to a google map in android. I set up my map and call the async task with this:

```
public class BreweryMap extends ActionbarMenu {

    BeerData e;
    String beerID;
    GoogleMap map;

    //get beer details from bundle
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_brewerymap);


        //get beer data
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        String breweryID = extras.getString("breweryID");

        map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                .getMap();



        //todo: get brewery latt and long and add marker
        //construct url
        String url = "http://api.brewerydb.com/v2/brewery/"+ breweryID +"?key=myKeyformat=json&withLocations=y";

        Log.d("map", url);
        //async task to get beer taste tag percents
        new AddBreweryMapMarkerJSON(this,map).execute(url);
```

when the asycn task is called I parse the json returned for a long and latt and attempt to add the marker to my map. I am retrieving a long and latt value from the json, which I know from my logs. The marker just is not being placed on the map.

```
public class AddBreweryMapMarkerJSON extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    Context c;
    private ProgressDialog Dialog;
    GoogleMap mapIn;

    public AddBreweryMapMarkerJSON(Context context, GoogleMap map)
    {
        c = context;
        mapIn = map;
        Dialog = new ProgressDialog(c);
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return readJSONFeed(arg0[0]);
    }

    protected void onPreExecute() {
        Dialog.setMessage("Getting brewery information");

        Dialog.setTitle("Loading");
        Dialog.setCancelable(false);
        Dialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result){

        try{

            Log.d("map", "in try");
            JSONObject o = new JSONObject(result);

            Log.d("brewery", result);


            String longitude = getLong(o);
            String latt = getLatt(o);



            double longDouble = Double.parseDouble(longitude);
            double lattDouble = Double.parseDouble(latt);

            //add marker
            mapIn.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(new LatLng(longDouble, lattDouble))
                    .title("Hello world"));



        }
        catch(Exception e){

        }

        Dialog.dismiss();

    }

    public String getName(JSONObject json){
        String holder;



        try{
            holder = json.getJSONObject("data").getString("name");

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            holder = "N/A";
        }



        return holder;

    }



    public String getIcon(JSONObject json){
        String holder;



        try{
            holder = json.getJSONObject("data").getJSONObject("images").getString("large");

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            holder = "N/A";
        }



        return holder;

    }

    public String getDescription(JSONObject json){
        String holder;



        try{
            holder = json.getJSONObject("data").getString("description");

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            holder = "N/A";
        }



        return holder;

    }


    public String getYear(JSONObject json){
        String holder;



        try{
            holder = json.getJSONObject("data").getString("established");

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            holder = "N/A";
        }



        return holder;

    }

    public String getLatt(JSONObject json){
        String holder;



        try{
            holder = json.getJSONObject("data").getJSONArray("locations").getJSONObject(0).getString("latitude");

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            holder = "null";
        }



        return holder;

    }

    public String getLong(JSONObject json){
        String holder;



        try{
            holder = json.getJSONObject("data").getJSONArray("locations").getJSONObject(0).getString("longitude");

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            holder = "null";
        }



        return holder;

    }

    public String readJSONFeed(String URL) {
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(URL);
        try {
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
            StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
            int statusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();
            if (statusCode == 200) {
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                InputStream inputStream = entity.getContent();
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    stringBuilder.append(line);
                }
                inputStream.close();
            } else {
                Log.d("JSON", "Failed to download file");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("readJSONFeed", e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
        return stringBuilder.toString();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here seemed to be that it did not like creating a LatLng inside adding the marker. By changing this:

```
//add marker
            mapIn.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(new LatLng(longDouble, lattDouble))
                    .title("Hello world"));
```

to this, fixed the marker not being added:

```
double longDouble = Double.parseDouble(longitude);
            double lattDouble = Double.parseDouble(latt);

            LatLng positionOne = new LatLng(lattDouble, longDouble);

            //add marker
            mapIn.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(positionOne)
                    .title(name));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to put the code which makes the map modification in a handler, then send a message to the handler from the AsyncTask. Normally, interface modifications must be made in the main thread, while the AsyncTask obviously runs in a side thread.

Comment: hmm, never ventured into handlers before I will look into it.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to animate your camera postion of google map to the specific position like

CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder().target(latLng) 
        .zoom(12) // Sets the zoom
        .tilt(30) // Sets the tilt of the camera to 30 degrees
        .build(); // Creates a CameraPosition from the builder
    // .bearing(90) // Sets the orientation of the camera to east
    gMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));

Comment: not sure what format your latLng is in, I have two doubles, one for latt and one for long.

Answer (score 0):

get the Lat/Lng points from your JSON string then create a List of `LatLng points from your JSON array

```
ArrayList<LatLng> points = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
```

loop through the string and add to the list

```
points.add(new LatLng(lat,lng));
```

the return the list in your `doInBackground`

```
return points;
```

then in your `onPostExecute` loop through the list and plot each one

```
public void onPostExecute(ArrayList points){
    for(LatLng point : points){
        //plot the point to the map
    }
}
```

you of course also have to change your return type when you declare your class

```
AsyncTask<String, Void, ArrayList<LatLng>>
```

Comment: not sure how this is different then mine other then you are using multiple points. I am already trying to add the map point in on post execute.

Comment: @Mike its different because you are doing all the parsing in the background and aonly returning points to loop through them. Then with the list you can loop through and plot each latlng. If the list is empty that means there is an exception happening somewhere since you dont log the exception when you parse how will you know if one happens? Never ever not log an exception, have you tried debugging to make sure no exception is happening?